# Your own comments do not have the same spacing as others' comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

Your own comments have a different vertical spacing than comments made by others (Chrome, Firefox, IE11 at least):

> [image]

This is because the minimum vertical spacing is currently dictated by the comment actions table, and your own comments do not have a "flag" action and so do not contain that row. This allows them to be vertically smaller than comments that have a "flag" action.

Just to be clear: Expected behavior is that my own comment would have the same wide vertical spacing as the others; that is, space for the flag icon would be allocated despite the flag option not actually being available for my own comments.

There is another comment spacing issue at [Comment vote vertical spacing is inconsistent on IE9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181560/comment-vote-vertical-spacing-is-inconsistent-on-ie9). I am not sure if they are related; that one is IE-specific and pertains to the vote counter positions, and the answer seems to indicate that it is related to the delete button, rather than the comment actions layout tables.

Comment: since you seem to know what causes this, let me ask you instead of asserting that it is: is this a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181560/comment-vote-vertical-spacing-is-inconsistent-on-ie9 ? There are details in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194068/comment-score-is-misaligned-for-own-single-line-comments?rq=1 which **is** a dupe of mine

Comment: I don't *think* it's a dupe; the votes seem to be aligned correctly. I'm referring to my own comment specifically being narrower than the rest (i.e. the whitespace below the others that is not below mine), rather than misaligned vote counts. Also this is on all browsers, not just IE. *But* the cause could be the same, maybe - perhaps it's related to the lack of a second table row in the comment actions area (although the answer on that post cites the delete button). So, I'm not sure. I'll let others decide if it's a dupe.

Comment: Caused by hidden flag icon.  I suppose the whole list jumping around like a badger on crack whenever your mouse hovers over it is the reason why they allocate the space for it.  Personally, I think they should move the flag icon to the end of the comment and be done with it.

Comment: @Won't I wouldn't know where I was looking to click tho... Maybe next to the up arrow would work, not next to it?

Comment: @Tim http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243858/display-comment-flag-next-to-vote-instead-of-below-to-reduce-whitespace - I didn't really notice *this* bug until I started looking closely at the comment spacings as a result of that feature request.

Comment: @Won't Just to be clear; the spacing I *expect* to see is actually the wider one everywhere (that is, allocate space for the hidden flag icon even on comments that aren't flaggable). As for *removing* the space entirely, see feature request linked in my previous comment.